# Calculated Properties based on properties of underlying Entities in Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a core data model with an entity “Day” which contains zero or more “Workout”s. The day entity has numerous properties which are calculated by summing over all the workouts. eg totalKM sums the km property value of all the workouts.

I just can’t get this to work.

I can get the totals to appear by overriding the value(forKey) method:

```
public override func value(forKey key: String) -> Any? {
    if(key == "swimSeconds"){
        var swimSeconds: Int64 = 0
        if let array = workouts?.allObjects{
            for w in array{
                let workout: Workout = w as! Workout
                if (workout.sport == Workout.SPORT.Swim.rawValue){
                    swimSeconds += workout.seconds
                }
            }
        }
        return swimSeconds
    }else{
        return super.value(forKey: key)
    }
}
```

However it means if the underlying workout is changed this is not reflected in the value shown for the total in the Day entity. Also it just feels like this is not the right thing to do - I shouldn’t need to override this method.

I’ve tried creating the NSManagedObject subclass using Xcode but that creates an Extension with all the @NSManaged variables but this just gives loads of errors “Extensions may not contain stored properties” which is only fixed by removing @NSManaged.

I tried creating my own Extension to Day and have a property with just a getter:

```
var totalSwimSeconds: Int64{
    get{
        var swimSeconds: Int64 = 0
        if let array = workouts?.allObjects{
            for w in array{
                let workout: Workout = w as! Workout
                if (workout.sport == Workout.SPORT.Swim.rawValue){
                    swimSeconds += workout.seconds
                }
            }
        }
        return swimSeconds
    }
}
```

This method produces a runtime error of: 
entity Day is not key value coding-compliant for the key "totalSwimSeconds"

I’ve searched online to see if I can find an example of this but all the examples are just simple cases of combining properties within the given entity (e.g. age from DOB, of full name for first and last name) that a more complex calculation looking at properties included in other entities.

How do I create a calculated property in Core Data which will calculate from underlying Entities and update when they update ?

[I am using Xcode 9 with Swift 4]

Comment: What code line gives you "not key value coding-compliant"?

Comment: I have a text field which is bound to the Day entity Array Controller selection with a model key path of totalSwimSeconds - I believe this is causing the run time exception. Am very new to SWIFT and xCode so am probably missing how to drill down on this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Swift 4 add the attributes `@objc` and `dynamic` to make the computed property key-value coding compliant.

```
@objc dynamic var totalSwimSeconds: Int64 { ...
```

Edit:

To observe the `workouts` property override `keyPathsForValuesAffectingValue` in `Day`

```
override class func keyPathsForValuesAffectingValue(forKey key: String) -> Set<String> {
    switch key {
    case "totalSwimSeconds": return Set(["workouts"])
    default: return super.keyPathsForValuesAffectingValue(forKey:key)
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you. Thats made a big difference. The property is now showing correctly. It still does not update when the value in the underlying Workout entity changes.

Comment: You could implement the class method [`keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1414299-keypathsforvaluesaffectingvaluef) to get a simple key value observing

Comment: struggling with what the key path syntax is. I have an entity Day which has zero or many "Workout"s via a relationship "workouts" - this needs to update if the "seconds" property changes. I've tried "workouts.seconds" and "Workout.seconds" as the key path. Neither work. Any suggestions?

Comment: thanks. That still isn't quite what I need. Now that updates if I add a workout. I need to update if the seconds property in a workout changes.

Comment: I'd tried that and got an error:  [<_NSFaultingMutableSet 0x60000003d080> addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:] is not supported. Key path: seconds
2017-10-16 13:43:07.786474-0700 Training Diary[2456:98475]

Comment: Yes, I suspected that, therefore I wrote *try*

Comment: lol! Thanks for trying.Wish they had some documentation on key paths. Haven't found anything that shows the key path syntax to dig down in to a property of an Entity linked via a relationship

Comment: Another *try* : `return Set(["workouts.allObjects.seconds"]` but I guess it works only in Objective-C because `allObjects` in Swift returns `[Any]` and has no idea about the `seconds` property.

Comment: whilst investigating something else I found the answer to this under the FAQ for Core Data: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.html - turns out it's just not possible  to do what I'm trying. New to stackoverflow - should I add this as an answer to my question ?